# How can I load a tab via a link on my web application?

Tags: html, css, jsp

thanks for your time firstly.

**Problem:** I am trying to link to a profile page on my web application from a number of different places, how can I have a button redirect to a certain tab on this page?

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="card card-tab">
    <div class="card-header">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="tab1" class="active">
          <a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="tab2">
          <a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Alerts</a>
        </li>
        <li role="tab3">
          <a href="#tab3" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
        <li role="tab4">
          <a href="#tab4" aria-controls="tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Admin</a>
        </li>
        </sec:authorize>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

When I click a tab I can see it will be amending the url to /profile#tab1/2/3 etc however linking to that directly just displays the profile page.

https://github.com/symonk/Release-Management/blob/master/Releases/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/profile.jsp

I'm guessing some Javascript will do the trick, but im not really sure where to begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I browsed the link you gave, you use Bootstrap for the tabs and I noticed you also use jQuery.
A solution for you might be to use anchors in URL and activate the tab based on this.
For example if you go to http://sample-env.qp3bsthmnq.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/profile#tab3

After having added this in your code :

```
var loadTab = function() {
    var tabId = location.hash;
    if(tabId !== undefined && $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + tabId + '"]') !== undefined) {
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    loadTab();
});
```

This must have activated the tab with id #tab3

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gilles, apologies my amazon AWS instance has actually gone offline temporarily, i added a link to the github source for the page, I will try this out asap

Comment: No problem, I had the time to access this before it went off.

Feel free to tell me, whenever you can, whether or not my answer has been useful to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Gilles, thanks it worked a treat. can now link appropriately to the /profile page and tab of my choice, thanks

Comment: I edited my answer because ideally you want to test if any anchor was sent in URL and if the tab exists.
Could you accept my answer if this has suit your needs?

Many thanks.

Cheers!